# matlab eventdata of uitable returned empty

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run a GUIDE app in Matlab, but I encounter a problem: when I try to access the location of the selected cell in a ui table, the variable holding it (eventdata.Indices) quickly changes back to an empty vector.
Here's my CellSelectionCallback function:

```
function varargout = ChannelMatrix(varargin)
% CHANNELMATRIX MATLAB code for ChannelMatrix.fig
%      CHANNELMATRIX, by itself, creates a new CHANNELMATRIX or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = CHANNELMATRIX returns the handle to a new CHANNELMATRIX or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      CHANNELMATRIX('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in CHANNELMATRIX.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      CHANNELMATRIX('Property','Value',...) creates a new CHANNELMATRIX or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before ChannelMatrix_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to ChannelMatrix_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDEs Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help ChannelMatrix

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 14-Oct-2015 17:06:14

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @ChannelMatrix_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @ChannelMatrix_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before ChannelMatrix is made visible.
function ChannelMatrix_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to ChannelMatrix (see VARARGIN)
clc
% Choose default command line output for ChannelMatrix
handles.output = hObject;
%CONNECT TO SWITCHER
matrixes=cell(12,6,26);
setappdata(0,'matrixes',matrixes);
set(handles.listbox1,'Value',1);
setappdata(0,'index_selected',1); %force Alpha for deafult selection
% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes ChannelMatrix wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = ChannelMatrix_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;



% --- Executes when selected cell(s) is changed in uitable1.
function uitable1_CellSelectionCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to uitable1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  structure with the following fields (see UITABLE)
%   Indices: row and column indices of the cell(s) currently selecteds
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% --- Executes when selected cell(s) is changed in uitable1.
try 
    currow = eventdata.Indices(1);
    curcol = eventdata.Indices(2);
    adata=get(handles.uitable1,'Data');
    if adata{currow,curcol} == 'V'
      adata{currow,curcol} = '';
    else 
       adata{currow,curcol} = 'V';
    end

    set(hObject,'Data',adata);
end

% --- Executes on button press in cls_ch.
function cls_ch_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to cls_ch (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
index_selected = getappdata(0,'index_selected');  %get the number of selected item in listbox
matrixes = getappdata(0,'matrixes'); %get current selection of measurments
table = get(handles.uitable1,'data'); %get the selected channels for this measure
for i=3:14
    for j=1:6
        if table{i-2,j}=='V'
            matrixes{i-2,j,index_selected}='V'; %preform scan and check - add to matrixes selcted values
        end
    end
end
%save changes
set(handles.uitable3,'Data',matrixes(:,:,index_selected)); 
setappdata(0,'matrixes',matrixes);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in opn_ch.
function opn_ch_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to opn_ch (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
index_selected = getappdata(0,'index_selected');  %get the number of selected item in listbox
matrixes = getappdata(0,'matrixes'); %get current selection of measurments
table = get(handles.uitable1,'data'); %get the selected channels for this measure
for i=3:14
    for j=1:6
        if table{i-2,j}=='V'
            matrixes{i-2,j,index_selected}=''; %preform scan and check - add to matrixes selcted values
        end
    end
end
%save changes
set(handles.uitable3,'Data',matrixes(:,:,index_selected)); 
setappdata(0,'matrixes',matrixes);
guidata(hObject, handles);

% --- Executes on button press in opn_all.
function opn_all_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to opn_all (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
matrixes=cell(12,6,26);
setappdata(0,'matrixes',matrixes); %sets up a new matrix 
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',cell(12,6)); 
set(handles.uitable3,'Data',cell(12,6)); 
set(handles.listbox1,'Value',1);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in clr_selection_btn.
function clr_selection_btn_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to clr_selection_btn (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',cell(12,6));

% --- Executes on selection change in listbox1.
function listbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to listbox1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns listbox1 contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from listbox1
matrixes=getappdata(0,'matrixes');
index_selected=get(hObject,'Value');
setappdata(0,'index_selected',index_selected);
set(handles.uitable3,'Data',matrixes(:,:,index_selected)); 
set(handles.uitable1,'Data',cell(12,6)); 
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function listbox1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to listbox1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: listbox controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @excaza matlab returns an error saying the the size of eventdata is zero, which cannot be right since it should hold the parameters of the selected cell's location.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with the provided code.

Comment: @excaza I've added the entire M-file. Note that this issue is resolved by just ignoring the error using the try-catch function, but this is just a fix-up as the error still occurs (though the variable is still readable - meaning both the try and the catch will operate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is nothing anything wrong in the definition of your `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback` function.

I've built a simple GUI consisting of just a `uitable` and executing step by step the callback in debug mode this is what actually happens:

- when you `left-click` on a cell's table, the `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback` is correctly called
- everything goes right up to the `set(hObject,'Data',adata);` instruction and `eventdata.Indices` array contains the row and column index of the selected cell (ref. to the `Function Call Stack` in the following picture)

[image]

- as the `set(hObject,'Data',adata);` function is executed, automatically a new call to `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback` is made by MatLab (probably somehow triggered by `set`. In the next picture, you can see the second (recursive) call to `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback` in the `Function Call Stack` and the white and green pair of arrows in the edit window the debug mode

[image]

- since the second call is not generated by an actual user selection of a cell, the `eventdata.Indices` is empty therefore an error is generated when the `currow = eventdata.Indices(1);` is executed

So, this is why when you click on a cell, its content is correctly set to "V" or to an empty string as you expeced but, at the same time (actually, after the time MatLab needs to make second call to `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback`) the GUI crashes.

I do not know if this might be considered a MatLab's `bug`, nevertheless I did not find any way to prevent the second call to `uitable1_CellSelectionCallback`.

A possible solution, not so far from yours (using `try-catch`) could be insert the present callback code in a `if` block checking if `isempty(eventdata.Indices)` (that is to replace `try` with `if`).

This will prevent the second call be "effective" and the generation of the error, which is not avoided by using `try-catch` (even if does not prevent the second call to happen).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I wanted to clarify something: by using the `if` statement I actually make MATLAB ignore the second call to the function at it's entirety?
Also, as I'm using R2013b, I'd recommend that you'd check the dot-notation instead of the `set` function for future reference.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy I've been of use to you. The `if` block does not prevent the second call which is (according to what I've understood) somehow generated automatically by the `set` function you use to update the `table ` content ( `set(hObject,'Data',adata)`) but it catches the fact that when the second call is made, the `eventdata.Indices` array is empty and does not allows executing the remaining part of the code. This, in turn, prevents generating the error you got. With respect to your comment about `dot notation`: it has been introduced in R2014b, while I'm using R2012.

Comment: When you think about it, it makes sense: once you've updated the data MATLAB thinks that you're done with that cell so the cell changes - to no selection, so `CellSelectionCallback` function is called with an empty parameter to signify that no cell is selected.
Regarding the `dot notation`, it'll be lovely if someone else reading this in the future could test it with the newer versions.